# X2Go: How to enable/disable

Tags: systemd, services, remote-desktop, x2go

[Documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X2go#Start_X2Go_server_daemon) and various internet answers suggest `x2goserver` will have a service on systemd systems which can be started (or stopped, etc) with `systemctl start x2goserver`.

However, there is no such service on my system (Fedora 30 MATE):

> Unit x2goserver.service could not be found.

There is also no process by this name except for `x2gocleansessions`:

```
$ pgrep -la x2go
1808 /usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions
```

Yet, X2Go is working. Has its process or service been named something else now?

How can X2Go be turned off or on?

Answer (score 0):

If your `x2gocleansessions` with PID `$pid` has been started by `systemd`, you can find out which service started it by issuing

```
$ systemctl status $pid
```

Comment: That would be `x2gocleansessions.service`